# CGDisplayStream - how to hide cursor on MacOS in Swift?

Tags: swift, macos, core-graphics

I'm using `CGDisplayStream` to capture MacOS display. The application has been created using Swift Package Manager and is built with Swift 5.0.1 as a command-line tool.

As I want to render the cursor on viewer (client) side, I need to hide the cursor on server side.

The documentation lists [`CGDisplayStream.showCursor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgdisplaystream/1454924-showcursor) as a property that controls whether to show the cursor or not, but I can't get it to work using following code:

```swift
func StreamDisplay(displayId: CGDirectDisplayID, width: Int, height: Int) -> CGDisplayStream?{
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "label")
    let displayStreamProps : [CFString : Any] = [
        CGDisplayStream.showCursor: kCFBooleanFalse as Any
    ]
    return CGDisplayStream(
       dispatchQueueDisplay: displayId,
       outputWidth: width,
       outputHeight: height,
       pixelFormat: Int32(k32BGRAPixelFormat),
       properties: displayStreamProps as CFDictionary,
       queue: queue)
}
```

Using the above, the cursor is still displayed as part of frame updates (MacOS 10.15.4).

Tried also following, but no luck:

```swift
CGDisplayStream.showCursor: kCFBooleanFalse!
```

and

```swift
CGDisplayStream.showCursor: false
```

I've observed that OBS-Studio [which uses the same API](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio/blob/f81cd29e0bf49692b172991d85535788dd83ac31/plugins/mac-capture/mac-display-capture.m#L207), has a "Show Cursor" option when capturing display:

[image: obs]

However it has no effect when recording - the cursor is visible even when the checkbox is not checked.

Is there a known limitation in MacOS, are there any prerequisites for the application to control that setting, or does the code need to look different?

Comment: It seems that there might be a bug on the macOS SDK -- please see https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio/issues/3961. For me, the code worked on 10.15.7 but not on 11.0.

Comment: This commit message also might be helpful for you: https://github.com/obsproject/obs-studio/commit/a892fa9e33d9c91db40af2952076b67154bed9bc